# How to show list of available Wifi networks in a DIALOG form in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash

I have written a program that allows to configure Wifi via the command line. I am trying to make `dialog` show the list of available networks (with `nmcli dev wifi list`) off to the side.

I tried setting the `--backtitle` argument of the `dialog` command to the result of `nmcli dev wifi list`.

```sh
function forum(){
    dialog --ok-label "Submit" \
        --backtitle "$(nmcli dev wifi list)" \
        --title "Wifi management" \
        --form "Connect to wifi" \
        15 50 0 \
        "SSID:"         1 1 "$ssid"     1 10 40 0 \
        "Password:"     3 1 "$passwd"       3 10 40 0 \
    2>&1 1>&3
}
```

The issue seems to be coming from this line: `--backtitle "$(nmcli dev wifi list)" \`

I expected the dialog to show the full output of `nmcli dev wifi list`, but instead it only outputted the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't! Only one string for '--backtitle'.

Try this:

```
function forum(){
    dialog --ok-label "Submit" \
        --backtitle "Connect to wifi" \
        --title "Wifi management" \
        --form "$(nmcli dev wifi list)" \
        15 50 0 \
        "SSID:"         1 1 "$ssid"     1 10 40 0 \
        "Password:"     3 1 "$passwd"       3 10 40 0 \
    2>&1 1>&3
}
```